# OpenCV: Convert Mat into UChar4

Tags: c++, opencv

I've just completed the Udacity Parallel programming stage 2 course, and I'm now implementing what I've learnt into a basic app with OpenCV which applies a gaussian blur to a constant stream of images coming through a webcam.

I'm loading frames into a `Mat` object, and whilst in my loop I want to call a method `gaussian_cpu`, the only problem is it requires a uchar4 to be passed to both the input and output parameters. How would I convert a `Mat` object to `uchar4`?

```
// Keep processing frames - Do CPU First
while(cpu_frames > 0)
{
    cout << cpu_frames << "\n";
    camera >> frameIn;

    gaussian_cpu(frameIn, frameOut, numRows(), numCols(), h_filter__, 9);

    imshow("Source", frameIn);
    imshow("Dest", frameOut);

    // 2ms delay to prevent system from being interrupted whilst drawing the new frame
    waitKey(2);
    cpu_frames--;
}
```

My method signature then looks like this:

```
void gaussian_cpu(
                const uchar4* const rgbaImage,       // input image from the camera
                uchar4* const outputImage,           // The image we are writing back for display
                size_t numRows, size_t numCols,      // Width and Height of the input image (rows/cols)
                const float* const filter,           // The value of sigma
                const int filterWidth                // The size of the stencil (3x3) 9
             )
```

I need to use uchar4 so I can split the channels, do my convolution and then recombine the channels to return the output image.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

opencv generally uses bgr, 3 channel Mats, but a basic:

```
Mat bgra;
cvtColor( frameIn, bgra, CV_BGR2BGRA );
```

will generate an (unused) 4th channel. now you probably have to allocate mem for you outputImage:

```
Mat frameOut( bgra.size(), bgra.type() );
```

then you can feed those into your gaussian_cpu():

```
int filterWidth=5;
float *filter = ... // your job, not mine ;)
gaussian_cpu( (uchar4*)(bgra.data), (uchar4*)(frameOut.data), bgra.rows, bgra.cols, filter, filterWidth );
```

Comment: That looks promising - what does `.data` appear like in the method sig? Will it be uchar or something different :)

Comment: uchar* Mat::data (that's how it holds any kind of data)

Comment: 4th channel is an optional alpha ;)

Comment: just note, that there's no alpha in images from the webcam ! but if you use imread("my.png", -1); then yes !

Comment: Ah very interesting - this is my first real deep dive into the low level world of things, have to say I'm loving it, despite the occasional headaches when wrestling with compiler errors ;) 
Thanks again for your help man :)